# Need help on using Spark Filter

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am new in Apache spark, need help in forming either SQL query or spark filter on dataframe.

Below is how my data is formed, i.e. i have large amount of users which contains below data.

> `{  "User1":"Joey",  "Department": ["History","Maths","Geography"] }`

I have multiple search conditions like below ones, wherein i need to search array of data based on operator defined by user say for example may be and / or.

> ```
> {
>  "SearchCondition":"1",
>  "Operator":"and",
>  "Department": ["Maths","Geography"]
> }
> ```

Can point me to a path of how to achieve this in spark ?

Thanks, 
-Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you use Scala and you have parsed the data in a DataFrame

```
val df = spark.read.json(pathToFile)
```

I would use DataSets for this because they provide type safety

```
case class User(department: Array[String], user1: String)
val ds = df.as[User]
def pred(user: User): Boolean = Set("Geography","Maths")subsetOf(user.department.toSet)
ds.filter(pred _)
```

You can read more about DataSets [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#creating-datasets) and [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset).

If you prefer to use Dataframes you can do it with user defined functions

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val pred = udf((arr: Seq[String]) => Set("Geography","Maths")subsetOf(arr.toSet))
df.filter(pred($"Department"))
```

At the same [package](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) you can find a spark built-in function for this. You can do

```
df.filter(array_contains($"Department", "Maths")).filter(array_contains($"Department", "Geography"))
```

but someone could argue that this is not so efficient and the optimizer can`t improve it a lot.

Note that for each search condition you need a different predicate.

Comment: Thanks Konstantinos it worked for me... but i am a bit confused over my data, as i have most of my data in Json format is there any link or something which tells how to model big data in spark world..